# Best practice way to handle variable content margin?

Tags: html, css

Ok, so a quick site that I am throwing together for a friend has about 20 static pages.  Each one with a small amount of content.  the div Container contains, well, the div  Content, and the div Content contains, obviously, the content that changes on each page.

Now, depending on the length of the content, I want a different margin at the top.  The less content, then the larger the margin.  Simply an aesthetic choice. For example, if the content almost fills the static sized container, there is less padding, but a 1 line page of content might be 1/3 of the way down the static container.   Centering the content in the div wont do, as that creates too large of a margin.

Whats the best way to handle this?  A new class for each content with a different margin?  A new Id, so that it is in its own special div positioned or margined differently? Inline css on each page to override the standard css for div Content?  A differnt spacer div inside Container before Content on each page?  Some sort of scripting along the lines of margin of Content = (ContainerHeight - ContentHeight) / 3?

Whats the acceptable way of doing this?  I don't want to get into bad habits.

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is an option, you can calculate the height of your content box and set a top margin according to the formula you prefer.

In jquery it would be something like:

```
c_height = $("#Content").height();
c_margin = Math.floor( /* your formula */ );
$("#Content").css("margin-top", c_margin + "px");
```

(not sure about the `"px"` part...)

Answer (score 0):

I would go the simple route, and define a single upper margin globally, with inline CSS to override it in pages that need it. Suppose you wind up editing one of the one-line pages to add more content - in that case you'd presumably would want to change the layout for that page and no other, so that change might as well be right there in the page itself.

On the other hand, the pages might feel more usable and consistent if you pick, say, three margin sizes and assign each page one of them based on how much content it has. Then, when you expanded a one-liner you might simply change its class from the small margin to the medium, so putting classes like `div.smallVMargin` into a central style sheet would make sense. What you want to avoid is an external CSS file with classes like `div.page16` or `div.margin25px`.